# numpy.nanmean of subsets of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to take subsets of elements and quickly apply `nanmean` to the associated columns, without looping.

For specificity, consider the reduction array `r=[0,2,3]`, and the data array

```
a=np.array([
             [2,3,4],
             [3,np.NaN,5],
             [16,66,666],
             [2,2,5],
             [np.NaN,3,4],
             [np.NaN,4,5],
             [np.NaN,5,4],
             [3,6,4.5],
           ])
```

then I want to get back

```
b = np.array([
             [2.5,3,4.5],
             [16,66,666],
             [2.5,4,4.5],
           ])
```

The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423408/product-of-array-elements-by-group-in-numpy-python) solves the problem (for a single column) by using [`reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html#numpy.ufunc.reduceat).  Unfortunately for me, since `nanmean` is not a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) that trick does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-liner to do this, because there are no `nan`-aware ufuncs in numpy.

But you can do something based on `reduceat`, after (temporarily) replacing all the nans in `a`:

For example, here's a quick function that accomplishes what you want:

```
def nanmean_reduceat(x, indices):
    mask = np.isnan(x)
    # use try-finally to make sure x is reset
    # to its original state even if an error is raised.
    try:
        x[mask] = 0
        return np.add.reduceat(x, indices) / np.add.reduceat(~mask, indices)
    finally:
        x[mask] = np.nan
```

then you can call

```
>>> nanmean_reduceat(a, [0, 2, 3])
array([[   2.5,    3. ,    4.5],
       [  16. ,   66. ,  666. ],
       [   2.5,    4. ,    4.5]])
```

Hope that helps!

*Edit: for brevity, I removed the empty `except` block and moved the `return` statement inside the try block. Because of the way `finally` statements work, the resetting of `x` is still executed!*